# Lógica sincronización bases de datos PHP MySQL MS Access

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

Quiero sincronizar dos bases de datos, cada una en un servidor distinto. La primera es una BBDD MySQL y la otra una BBDD MS Access. Con sincronizar me refiero a que en cuanto se haga un cambio en una de las dos tablas, en la otra tabla se refleje con la mayor rapidez posible. Os cuento la lógica que se me ha ocurrido a ver si os parece bien o si se os ocurre alguna idea para optimizarla:

1º) Leer todos los registros de ambas tablas y guardarlas en una variable. 
2º) Comparar, con un bucle anidado, fila por fila que todos los datos sean iguales. 
2a-Si todos los datos de la fila son iguales, pasamos a la siguiente fila. 
2b-Si hay diferencia de datos, consulto en un sistema de logs, cuál es el cambio más reciente, borro el que tenga el dato más antiguo e inserto el nuevo en la tabla correspondiente. Tras eso, paso a la siguiente fila. 
3º) Y así hasta que se llegue al final de la tabla. En ese momento, estarían actualizadas.

No sé cómo de eficiente lo veis o no. El problema es que no tengo ni idea de cómo crear el sistema de logs, ni si PHP es el mejor lenguaje para ello, o si será eficiente o no.

P.D. Con sistema de logs me refiero a almacenar en una BBDD la hora y el cambio realizado en cada campo.

Ya me comentáis, gracias.

Comment: La lógica no parece adecuada, la eficiencia para recorrer y comparar ambas tablas en cualquier lenguaje no va a resultar aceptable en determinado punto. El sistema de logs parece bien encaminado y podrías hacerlo con `triggers` para cada cambio en las tablas (insert, update, delete) y buscar estos cambios en una tarea programada que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Espero lo tomes a bien :)